# Why command create-react-app opens file explorer

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to create react application, but every time I put command create-react-app react-app it opens file explorer and that's it. Folder where I began cannot be deleted and it won't create application. Please help.

Comment: Are you trying with `npx create-react-app react-app` command as mentioned in [docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started/)?

Comment: Yes, but still won't work. It's like it's frozen, opens file explorer and everything stops.